# css input number field rendering weird on certain versions of ios

Tags: ios, css, input

The input number field doesn't render properly on ios. The number gets cut off at the bottom. It works for certain ios versions but not other ones. I'm stuck, please help

```
input[type=submit] {
    text-align: center;
}

.page_q3 input[type="number"] {
    height: 91px;
    width: 110px;
    color: #464356;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    font-size: 82px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #464356;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

<div class="page_q3">

    <div class="div_minus"><img src="<?=$templateDir?>/images/minus.jpg" class="minus" data-quantity="minus" data-field="<?=$inputName?>" /> </div>

    <div class="div_number"><input type="number" id="<?=$inputName ?>" name="<?=$inputName?>" value="<?=$_SESSION[$inputName]?>" placeholder="0" /> </div>

    <div class="div_plus"><img src="<?=$templateDir?>/images/plus.jpg"
    class="plus" data-quantity="plus" data-field="<?=$inputName?>" /> </div>
</div>
```

What it should look like
https://ibb.co/y8msSpL

what it actually looks like
https://ibb.co/rkbyPF5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try removing the `border-radius` and `padding` that are added by iOS by default:

```css
.page_q3 input[type="number"] {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0; 
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked, holy crap. This has stumped me for days. Thanks.